# How to SUMIF with an array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I can not get this calculation to work.

```
=SUMIF({C3,E3,G3,I3,K3,M3},"N",{D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3})
```

The array as the `RANGE` works fine but the array as the `SUM_RANGE` returns the error message:

> Argument must be a range

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Dean.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but see if this works

```
=SUMPRODUCT({C3,E3,G3,I3,K3,M3}="N",{D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try filter with offset:

`=SUM(FILTER(D3:N3,C3:M3="B"))`

[image]

why it's better:

- you use the entire ranges.
- the formula is shorter
- easy to add other conditions in a filter.

**Edit**

See also `sumif` with offset:

`=SUMIF(C3:M3,"B",D3:N3)`

Comment: Thanks Max, this solution works if my array is a range in the form of A3:Z3 but my actual array is grabbing values from all over the sheet. The RANGE looks like {A3,S2,G6,K8} and the SUM_RANGE is {B3, T2, H6, L8}

Comment: Note: This only works if you have a clear distinction between data types. It won't work in the arbitrary case, for instance if you want to sum one set of values based on other numbers. Something like `=SUM(FILTER(D3:N3,C3:M3>5))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for the sum(if()) pattern instead of sumif(). Try this:

```
=sum(arrayformula(if({C3,E3,G3,I3,K3,M3}="N",{D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3},0)))
```

**How this works**

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | N | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **3** |  |  | Y | 1 | N | 1 | Y | 1 | Y | 1 | N | 1 | Y | 1 |

- `{C3,E3,G3,I3,K3,M3}="N"` creates an array of 6 values. Each of the values in the array is `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether the corresponding cell in the input array is "N" or not. This is used as the `logical_expression` of the `if()`:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

- `{D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3}` creates an array of 6 values as well. You're already familiar with this, but I'm including it to point out that it is the `value_if_true` of the `if()`:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

- The `arrayformula()` allows the `if()` to return an array
- Now, the first temporary array that we created above is used as the `logical_expression` in the `if()`. The formula creates an output array equal in size to the input array.
- For each entry in the input, if `TRUE`, the output array is filled with the value from the same position in `value_if_true`. If `FALSE`, it uses the value from the `value_if_false,` which is `0`. In this example, the output array looks like:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

- `sum()` aggregates the array, which in this example returns `2`